# Call One button from another Button with delay in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I have Button1 with this code:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles    Button1.Click

    Label2.Text = ""
    Label3.Text = ""
    Label4.Text = ""

End Sub
```

and want to call button1 when click on button2 with delay, for example when clicked on button2 after 20 seconds apply button1.

in button2 code:

```
 Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles      Button2.Click

    Button1_Click(sender, e)
     Label6.Text = ""
End Sub
```

how can I make it with delay of time so first clear label6.text then after delay clear labe2 and 3 and 4.

Comment: Do avoid "calling a button".  Use a timer, its Tick event can call a private method that the button's Click event handler can use as well.  Do consider if you still need the button, it is not likely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Hans pointed out avoid calling another button.  Create a private sub that both buttons can use.  Then use a timer for the 20 second delay.  Something like this:

```
'Declare a timer with a tick rate of 20 seconds
Dim Timer As New Timer With {.Interval = 20000}
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    ClearLabels2To4()
End Sub

'Create this as a separate sub, so it can be used by both buttons.
Private Sub ClearLabels2To4()
    Label2.Text = ""
    Label3.Text = ""
    Label4.Text = ""
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    ClearLabels2To4()
    'Start the 20 second timer
    Timer.Start()
End Sub

Private Sub Timer_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Label6.Text = ""
    'Stop the timer so it doesn't continually fire every 20 seconds
    Timer.Stop()
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    'Create a handler for the timer ticks
    AddHandler Timer.Tick, AddressOf Timer_Tick
End Sub
```

Comment: Good answer. Not a good idea to name your Timer variable the same name as the class. Also you can skip the `AddHandler` if you use WithEvents. `Private WithEvents DelayTimer As New Timer With {.Interval = 20000}`

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna or need to use button, the following code might be worked.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Label1.Text = ""
    Label2.Text = ""
    Label3.Text = ""
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Label6.Text = ""
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(20000)
    Button1_Click(sender, e)
End Sub
```

The following link give a way to pause or delay the process [the link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/03281eb7-f37b-4f88-b634-1f139b12f447/delay-or-pause-my-vb-code?forum=vbgeneral).

Hopefully it helps. Thanks.

Comment: I tried your way and I got that when clicked on button2 it delays to activate button2 not button1 and didn't give me what I want!